# Read CSV file and check if contents exists in DB and then only insert else update

Tags: java, oracle, filereader

I am trying to read an uploading CSV file content and want to check if the Upload data having combinations of

“Id + Version (Actual, Budget, Forecast)+Year”

then should delete the existing record in DB having that combo and upload it.

Please help me how to check that,currently I have read all contents in my uploaded csv file using,

```
  while(fileItemsIterator.hasNext()){

  FileItem fileItem = fileItemsIterator.next();

  String fileValue=fileItem.getString();//This returns all my csv content

    }
```

### DB Call

```
   String existingUploadData ="SELECT ID,AMOUNT_TYPE,COST_YEAR FROM UPLOAD WHERE ID ='"+id+"'";

             log.debug ("====existingUploadData QUERY== "+existingUploadData );  

             PreparedStatement ps = (OraclePreparedStatement) DBConnect.getConnection().prepareStatement(existingUploadData);

             ResultSet  rs=ps.executeQuery();

             if(rs.next()) {
                    if(rs.getString("ID").equals(fileValue.contains("675"+""+""))) {

       //UPDATE EXISTING TABLE
                    }
                } else {

       //INSERT SQL
                }
```

**File Contents**

```
CSV FILE CONTENT SAMPLE
----------------------------

ID  |Cost Type| Year|   Leve1        |Level 2         |  I/P      | Vendor Type |   Vendor Name |  App.Ref  Remarks Amount  Unit
----|---------|-----|----------------|----------------|-----------|-------------|---------------|----------------------------------
675 |Actual   |2018 |   TCO Cost     |Solution Support|initiative|  3rd part    |   ABC         |   123      okk     22     EUR
675 |Actual   |2018 |  Net Book Value|  Software      |Project    | 3rd part    |   XYZ         |   234      good   11      EUR
675 |Actual   |2018 |   Number of FTE|  BUIT          | Project   | 3rd part    |    LMN        |   435      fine   50      FTE
```

Please help me how to check if 675+Actaul+2018 from CSV file already exists in my database and then do all CRUD operations accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the apache-commons-csv to get the values from csv rows

```
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(csvFileInputStream));      
CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withIgnoreEmptyLines().withFirstRecordAsHeader().withIgnoreHeaderCase().withTrim()));
```

This will make the library treat the first row as column headers and then you can process the rows as

```
List<CSVRecord> csvRecords = csvParser.getRecords();
for(CSVRecord csvRecord : csvRecords) {
            String id= csvRecord.get("ID");
            String costType = csvRecord.get("Cost Type");
            String costYear = csvRecord.get("Year");
            //Construct your query here
        }
```

You could always do a count query to check if the record exists in the database as :

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UPLOAD WHERE ID='"+ID+"' AND AMOUNT_TYPE='"+costType+"' AND COST_YEAR='"+costYear+"'";
```

If the returned count is 1 or more, you can be sure that this exists in the database, and take actions as necessary.

One more thing that could be done is(if the already existing record does not contribute to the new records data), rather than using the select query, you always delete the record before insertion ( if the record does not exist nothing will happen ) as :

```
String query = "DELETE FROM UPLOAD WHERE ID='"+ID+"' AND AMOUNT_TYPE='"+costType+"' AND COST_YEAR='"+costYear+"'";
```

and then fire the insert query, this makes you sure, that the record is never inserted twice.

Comment: Many Thanks Aman for answering.But the point is I dont know how to get the ID,Amount_type,etc values from the Uploaded CSV file seperately .

Comment: @Saranya I have made the changes to the answer for your request, see if it works for you.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion would be pure (PL/)SQL: use **external table** database feature which enables you to read the CSV file as if it was an *ordinary* Oracle table.

In order to use it, you'd have to have access to *directory* (an Oracle object which points to directory in file system; the most common location is the database server).

You'd be able to check whether data already exist in the target table (using a simple `SELECT` statement) and update it, or - if it doesn't exist - insert a new row. Consider using **MERGE** (which is also called *upsert* as you can UPdate or inSERT data using the same command).

Comment: This requires the file to be present in the SQL server's file system. Correct? if that's so, this may not be suitable to what the OP is asking.

Comment: @Aman, directory can be created elsewhere, not only the database server (although it is - as I've said - the most common option). Using UNC, it can be on any other computer that is accessible from the server.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Seems this is the best overall option then, optimized to perform better.